# Is there a way to extract only the value from "free" field of Get-PSDrive?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to take the value of free space from a drive, this is necessary to do an automatict procedure in a database server.

I got this script:

```
    $query_drive_mount_point = @"
    select distinct
    convert(varchar(512), b.volume_mount_point) as [volume],
    convert(varchar(512), b.logical_volume_name) as [logical_volume]
    from sys.master_files as [a]
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(a.database_id, a.[file_id]) as [b]
    "@

        [regex]$get_drive = '\w\:\\'
        [regex]$get_drive_name = '\w'
        [regex]$get_drive_space = '\d'
        $mount_point = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$server_ip\$sql_engine,$sql_port" -Username "$sql_user" -Password "$sql_password" -Database Master -Query "$query_drive_mount_point" 

        $get_disk = $get_drive.Matches($mount_point) | Foreach-Object {$_.Value}
        $get_disk_name = $get_drive_name.Matches($get_disk) | Foreach-Object {$_.Value}

        $size_bytes_string = Get-PSDrive $get_disk_name | Select-Object -Property Free
        [int]$size_bytes = $get_drive_space.Matches($size_bytes_string) | ForEach-Object {$_.Value} 
        $size_giga = ( ( ( $size_bytes )/1024 )/1024 )/1024
```

This code runs without problem until this line:

```
[int]$size_bytes = $get_drive_space.Matches($size_bytes_string) | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}
```

It throws this error:

```
There was not found overload for "Matches" and args numbers is "1".
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ $size_bytes = $get_drive_space.Matches($size_bytes_string) | ForEach- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

The last error is a traduction made by me, the os is in spanish.

Again, the objective is to store only the free space value.

Comment: What happens if you change `$size_bytes_string = Get-PSDrive $get_disk_name | Select-Object -Property Free` to `$size_bytes_string = Get-PSDrive $get_disk_name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Free`?

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I did it and it works flawlessly, thank you. Please post your answer.

Comment: @HaroldoPayaresSalgado also, `$size_bytes/1GB` will yield GB size rather than all of those divisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the value from the property you need, so this line:

```
$size_bytes_string = Get-PSDrive $get_disk_name | Select-Object -Property Free to
```

Should be changed to the following:

```
$size_bytes_string = Get-PSDrive $get_disk_name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Free
```

Alternatively you can format it as follows:

```
($size_bytes_string = Get-PSDrive $get_disk_name).Free
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have PS version 5:

```
PS C:\> (($PSVersionTable).PSVersion)

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  145
```

- if not version 5, try to import the storage module.

You can get this information easier by using the below commandlet:

```
Get-disk # the command name
Get-Command -Module storage -Verb get -Noun disk # module
```

onliner code to select the size of the first hdd (disk 0):

```
[math]::Round((Get-Disk -Number 0).Size /1GB)
```

**- Edited :**

> =========================================================================

if you load this assembly, you can get all the information you need,

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$sql = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server')
```

You can run this commandlet to find what information you can get :

```
    (($sql | gm) | measure).count
```

For example :

```
    write-host $dbs.Parent
    $dbs=$s.Databases
```

I believe you need a property called filegroup to get information about **ldf**&**mdf** files.

Comment: That's great, but there is a problem, it must be the drive where the database is installed and it should work even if the disk has a "funny" name, that´s why I use that simple query in the script.